# Adding a new column to data.frame whose values are random samples of one column and conditioned on another

Tags: r, dataframe, random, sample, mismatch

I want to add a new column (`category`) whose values (`a/b`) are random samples (without replacement) of the `id`-column, but conditioned on the value (`A/B`) in the `group`-column.
When trying to do so, however, the value in the `id` column changes--I don't understand why this is happening.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id=LETTERS[1:10], group=sample(c("1","2"), size=10, replace=T))
df$category <- NA

> table(df$group)
1 2 
6 4

df[df$id %in% sample(df[df$group=="1",]$id, size=4, replace=F),]$category <- "a" 
df[df$id %in% sample(df[df$group=="2",]$id, size=2, replace=F),]$category <- "b" 

> df
    id group category
 1   A     1        a
 2   B     1     <NA>
 3   B     1        a
 4   D     2        b
 5   E     1     <NA>
 6   F     2     <NA>
 7   G     2     <NA>
 8   H     2        b
 9   C     1        a
 10  E     1        a

> df$id==LETTERS[1:10]
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# this should be all TRUE
```

(Please feel free to edit title and question, if it is not expressed clearly enough)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that, the `i` is used for 'id'.  It would have worked if the `row.names` of the dataset is 'id'.  Here, we may need to `match` with 'id'

```
i1 <- with(df, match(sample(id[group == 1], size = 4, replace = FALSE), id))
df$category[i1] <- 'a'
```

and similarly for the second case

```
i2 <- with(df, match(sample(id[group == 2], size = 2, replace = FALSE), id))
df$category[i2] <- 'b'
```

-output

```
df
#   id group category
#1   A     1        a
#2   B     1     <NA>
#3   C     1        a
#4   D     2        b
#5   E     1        a
#6   F     2     <NA>
#7   G     2        b
#8   H     2     <NA>
#9   I     1     <NA>
#10  J     1        a

df$id==LETTERS[1:10]
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: Uhmm I did not know this `with()` function, it looks good code.

Answer (score 1):

This is weird, but it worked when I substitute the $ operator, by including the name of "category" inside the subsetting function. Like this:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id=LETTERS[1:10], group=sample(c("1","2"), size=10, replace=T))
df$category <- NA

df[df$id %in% sample(df[df$group=="1",]$id, size=4, replace=F), "category"] <- "a" 
df[df$id %in% sample(df[df$group=="2",]$id, size=2, replace=F), "category"] <- "b"
```

**Resulting this:**

```
   id group category
1   A     1        a
2   B     1     <NA>
3   C     1        a
4   D     2     <NA>
5   E     1     <NA>
6   F     2     <NA>
7   G     2        b
8   H     2        b
9   I     1        a
10  J     1        a


df$id==LETTERS[1:10]

# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```